# Optional inner join SQL

Tags: sql

I have this SQL code that does an inner join on 2 tables:

```
SELECT 
    c.*, 
    dc1.user_pemilik_nip AS lokasi1, 
    dc2.user_pemilik_nip AS lokasi2
FROM 
    certificate c
INNER JOIN 
    data_certificate dc1 ON c.seri = dc1.certificate_seri
                         AND dc1.part_certificate_name = 'Surat Ukur'
INNER JOIN  
    data_certificate dc2 ON c.seri = dc2.certificate_seri
                         AND dc2.part_certificate_name = 'BT dan STP'
```

As you can see, I `inner join` the same table twice `(data_certificate to dc1 and dc2)` with where/on condition is `part_certificate_name`, but, this sql script can't handle if 2 of condition for `part_certificate_name` there's only one, so `seri` with 1 `part_certificate_name` not showed, only `seri` with 2 `part_certificate_name`, how to handle that case, and btw is there simple SQL code similar with my case?

Comment: sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Is there a case that in `data_certificate` for the same `certificate_seri` there are 2 rows with `part_certificate_name` equal to 'Surat Ukur' and 'BT dan STP'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.*, dc1.user_pemilik_nip as lokasi1, dc2.user_pemilik_nip as lokasi2
FROM certificate c LEFT JOIN
     data_certificate dc1
     ON c.seri = dc1.certificate_seri AND
        dc1.part_certificate_name = 'Surat Ukur' LEFT JOIN
     data_certificate dc2
     ON c.seri = dc2.certificate_seri AND
        dc2.part_certificate_name = 'BT dan STP'
```

Answer (score 0):

If for each `certificate_seri` in `data_certificate` there is only 1 `part_certificate_name`, either `'Surat Ukur'` or `'BT dan STP'`, then you need only 1 join for both cases with the operator `IN` in the `ON` clause and with `CASE` expressions in the `SELECT` list to distinguish the columns:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       CASE WHEN dc.part_certificate_name = 'Surat Ukur' THEN dc.user_pemilik_nip AS lokasi1, 
       CASE WHEN dc.part_certificate_name = 'BT dan STP' THEN dc.user_pemilik_nip AS lokasi12
FROM certificate c INNER JOIN data_certificate dc 
ON c.seri = dc.certificate_seri AND dc.part_certificate_name IN ('Surat Ukur', 'BT dan STP');
```

If there may exist both values for each `certificate_seri`, then first aggregate in `data_certificate` and then join to `certificate`:

```
SELECT c.*, dc.lokasi1, dc.lokasi12
FROM certificate c 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT certificate_seri,
         MAX(CASE WHEN part_certificate_name = 'Surat Ukur' THEN user_pemilik_nip END) lokasi1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN part_certificate_name = 'BT dan STP' THEN user_pemilik_nip END) lokasi2
  FROM data_certificate 
  WHERE part_certificate_name IN ('Surat Ukur', 'BT dan STP')
  GROUP BY certificate_seri
) dc ON c.seri = dc.certificate_seri;
```